# DAQmxReadAnalogScalarF64 does what exactly?

Tags: c, windows, usb

I've been given the task of rewriting some legacy software written in C. Everything is going great except I've run across this function that I have no definition for. I was not given every library, and I can't find the purpose of this function anywhere.

I THINK it's used to read analog data from USB but I'm not sure. I'm particularly interested in the 3rd parameter, "data", and what this function does to it.

DAQmxReadAnalogScalarF64 (taskOut1, 10.0, &data, 0);

Comment: It seems pretty obvious that this probably reads from USB or something similar, but the client insists they have no such hardware. All input supposedly comes from the form, which I've already created and seems to be working fine. However this function is run before anything else, and would change the output if the data variable is altered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a function from the National Instruments libraries, from the depths of my mind, but I couldn't tell you what it does. You might find online docs at ni.com

Comment: @tinman, that's exactly right. Isaac, I think your client is telling porky pies. It's part of NI's DAQmx data acquisition device driver software: http://www.ni.com/dataacquisition/nidaqmx.htm. Their website is quite comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[The Googles](https://www.google.com/search?q=DAQmxReadAnalogScalarF64)* seem to believe that the third parameter should be the address of the 64-bit float that's going to be read.  (e.g. pointer to a `double`)

Answer (score 1):

The details of that function are in the NI-DAQmx C Reference Help that gets installed with the NI-DAQmx driver.  If your are only rewriting code and don't need to use the driver to work with NI DAQ hardware, you can download the manual here: http://digital.ni.com/manuals.nsf/websearch/C4B5B92E74F160C6862574560065F8BC

If you need to install the NI-DAQmx driver for testing and development, this can be found here: http://joule.ni.com/nidu/cds/view/p/id/2604/lang/en

The DAQmxReadAnalogScalarF64 reads multiple floating-point samples from a task that contains one or more analog input channels - basically, it is used to read data from data acquisition hardware.